# filling an array of structs from a file

Tags: c++

I am trying to fill an array of structs from a given file but it doesn't seem to read anything.

```cpp
/******************************************************************                 
 * READ FILE                                                                        
 * This function opens the given file name and saves the info                       
 * into an array.                                                                   
 ******************************************************************/
int readFile(const std::string dataFile, AccessRecord accessRecordArray[], int &cou\
nt)
{

 std::ifstream fin(dataFile.c_str());
   if (fin.fail())
      return -1;


   std::string file;

   while (!fin.eof())
   {
      fin >> file;
      count++;
   }

   std::cout << count << std::endl;

   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
      fin >> accessRecordArray[i].fileName;
      fin >> accessRecordArray[i].userName;
      fin >> accessRecordArray[i].timeStamp;
   }


   fin.close();

   return 0;
}
```

All this outputs is zero equal to the variable count. Can you help me see what I am missing?

Comment: I've declared the array of structs as AccessRecord accessRecordArray[500] in main.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you read fin until the end of file, then continue reading? seems like your are missing a `fin.seekg()` in there

Comment: I am only reading to the end of file to get the number of items in the file then using that number in my for loop. The for loop is where I am trying to fill my array of structs

Comment: I think you will need to reset fin by closing and then reopening it or by resetting it to the beginning which would be better. Hint: **seekg**

Comment: how do you use fin.seekg?

Comment: What ```fin << file```  does is the following: it overwrites the string and does not store it for further use. Furthermore, what is the purpose of the second loop? You could just store them while you are reading them. The second parameter is called by value and not by reference.

Comment: For starters: `while (!fin.eof())` is a red flag. That should be `while (fin >> file)`